# How can I resolve this ts(18048) error in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

the following snippet of code

```
onQuantityChange(change: ProductQuantityChange) {
    const product = this.products.find(prod => {
      return change.product.id === prod.id;
    });
    product.quantityInCart += change.changeInQuantity;
}
```

returns me a
`ts(18048) 'product' is possibly 'undefined'.`

I suppose the reason is that `product` depends on the `.find()` which can return no value at all. How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try question mark this.products?.find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
onQuantityChange(change: ProductQuantityChange) {
    const product = this.products.find(prod => prod.id === change.product.id);
    if (product)
        product.quantityInCart += change.changeInQuantity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking product before modifying it like:

```js
onQuantityChange(change: ProductQuantityChange) {
    const product = this.products.find(prod => change.product.id === prod.id);
    if(product)
      product.quantityInCart += change.changeInQuantity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**`OR operator` can also be used to handle undefined;**

```
(product || {}).quantityInCart += change.changeInQuantity;
```

```js
onQuantityChange(change: ProductQuantityChange) {
    const product = this.products.find(prod => {
      return change.product.id === prod.id;
    });
    (product || {}).quantityInCart += change.changeInQuantity;
}
```